# Use XSL template match for all HTML (not plain text) elements inside of a div

Tags: xml, xslt

I basically need to figure out how to select the interior of my div and have that display all of the HTML elements inside of it as HTML elements.  Everything I have tried has resulted in displaying plain text or keeping the exterior div.

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
</xsl:template>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="content/div/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Example 1: of potential XML content:

```
<content>
    <div id="definition" class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid reprehenderit consequatur voluptatem harum laudantium! Repellat nam laborum ipsum possimus, corrupti voluptate, iste odio vero nesciunt culpa assumenda nihil ducimus accusantium.</p>
    </div>
</content>
```

Example 2: of potential XML content:

```
<content>
    <div id="definition" class="block">
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
            <li>Sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Adipisicing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquid reprehenderit.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</content>
```

I need the XSLT to simply extract HTML elements inside the div like this...

For Example 1:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid reprehenderit consequatur voluptatem harum laudantium! Repellat nam laborum ipsum possimus, corrupti voluptate, iste odio vero nesciunt culpa assumenda nihil ducimus accusantium.</p>
```

For Example 2:

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Sit amet consectetur.</li>
    <li>Adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquid reprehenderit.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I need a wildcard selector or some sort of loop here.  I am really not very familiar with XML/XSLT/XPath at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="content/div">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that also copies the div.  I need just the interior.

Comment: No, I don't think it does that: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7m4 But you may have other things at work. You should edit your question and post a [mcve].

Comment: I appreciate the condescension of that response, but it does do that.  I actually just tried it and it brings the div with it.  How exactly would you frame my question differently?  It is as minimal as I could think to make it and I believe I mentioned the div being a problem as well.  This is easily verifiable also.

Comment: Have you looked at the demo I linked to?

Comment: I pulled up the link.  This is just frustrating.  It definitely isn't responding the same way in my file.

Comment: There is something that is causing this to drag the parent with it in my code.  This is at least helpful knowing that there is a deeper root cause.  Thank you!

Comment: @PhilipTheobald My example has XML, XSLT and a result. If you show us an XML and XSLT that produce a different result, we'll be able to tell why. That's what [mcve] means.

Comment: Compare this, this is the full file.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7m4/1

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7m4/2

The first link shows it broken, but using  <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:copy-of select="div/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
works.  Super weird.

Comment: Could you reduce this to only what's necessary to show the problem at hand?

Comment: Sorry.  Honestly, I'm really not familiar with this enough to reduce it.  If you look at line 139 of the XSL and lines 21 & 25 respectively, in the result, you should be able to see the issue.

Comment: The only thing I can tell with confidence is that your template at line 139 is not being applied to the `div` in question, because there's another template with higher priority handling it.

Comment: I spotted the issue there.  I was not calling the correct template in the previous selector.  That part was driving me crazy.  It seems to be working now.  Also, I didn't consider priority, I'll have to read about that.  I noticed some of the templates have priority attributes on them.  I just inherited this project.  My apologies for my initial response.  I made a bad assumption because I thought I had done exactly what you'd said.  I truly appreciate your responses.